# Generating date ranges

Tags: function-construction

How can I, in one line, generate all the dates with a constant day difference from one date to another?

For example, if I'm interested in dates in the interval staring from 24.4.2012 till 2015 and a 28 day difference.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perhaps this way:

```
Table[DatePlus[{2012, 4, 24}, 28*i], {i, 1, 40}]
```

> {{2012, 5, 22}, {2012, 6, 19}, {2012, 7, 17}, {2012, 8, 14}, {2012, 9,
>          11}, {2012, 10, 9}, {2012, 11, 6}, {2012, 12, 4}, {2013, 1, 
>         1}, {2013, 1, 29}, {2013, 2, 26}, {2013, 3, 26}, {2013, 4, 
>         23}, {2013, 5, 21}, {2013, 6, 18}, {2013, 7, 16}, {2013, 8, 
>         13}, {2013, 9, 10}, {2013, 10, 8}, {2013, 11, 5}, {2013, 12, 
>         3}, {2013, 12, 31}, {2014, 1, 28}, {2014, 2, 25}, {2014, 3, 
>         25}, {2014, 4, 22}, {2014, 5, 20}, {2014, 6, 17}, {2014, 7, 
>         15}, {2014, 8, 12}, {2014, 9, 9}, {2014, 10, 7}, {2014, 11, 
>         4}, {2014, 12, 2}, {2014, 12, 30}, {2015, 1, 27}, {2015, 2, 
>         24}, {2015, 3, 24}, {2015, 4, 21}, {2015, 5, 19}}

Of course you might want to finetune the number of 28-day intervals.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the built in `Calendar` functions :

```
Needs["Calendar`"]

Floor[DaysBetween[{2012, 4, 24}, {2015, 12, 31}]/28]

(* 48 *)

NestList[DaysPlus[#, 28] &, {2012, 4, 24}, 48]
```

Answer (score 7):

Single liner using currently available commands and avoiding the legacy issues.

```
NestList[DatePlus[#, 28] &, #1, 
   Round[DateDifference[##2]/28]] & @@ {{2012, 4, 24}, {2015, 12, 31}}
```

Answer (score 2):

[DateRange](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DateRange.html) (for versions 9.0+):

[image]

So using `{28, "Day"}` as the third argument:

```
DateRange[{2012, 4, 24}, {2015}, {28, "Day"}][[All,;;3]]
```

we get

> {{2012,4,24}, {2012,5,22}, {2012,6,19}, {2012,7,17}, {2012,8,14}, {2012,9,11},
>    {2012,10,9}, {2012,11,6}, {2012,12,4}, {2013,1,1}, {2013,1,29}, {2013,2,26},{2013,3,26},
>   {2013,4,23},{2013,5,21},{2013,6,18},{2013,7,16},{2013,8,13},{2013,9,10},{2013,10,8},
>   {2013,11,5},{2013,12,3},{2013,12,31},{2014,1,28},{2014,2,25},{2014,3,25},{2014,4,22},
>   {2014,5,20},{2014,6,17},{2014,7,15},{2014,8,12},{2014,9,9},{2014,10,7},{2014,11,4},
>   {2014,12,2},{2014,12,30}}